# 5V to 3.3V logic level converter

Tags: arduino, esp8266, logic-level

I am trying to connect an [ESP8266 module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) to an Arduino. Giving the fact that ESP8266 runs at 3.3V and the Arduino at 5V i need a logic level converter from 5V to 3V3.

Is there a way i can build one using discrete components? I searched the web and found recommendations for TXS0104E / 74LVC245 / BSS138, unfortunately none of the local shops sell them.

Although the 3.3V TX pin from the ESP8266 does not require a logic converter since Arduino will read the 3V3 signal as HIGH, i would like to add some protection for the wifi module. Is a 3.3V zenner diode a wise choice for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to dig through a datasheet to figure stuff out that you should already have figured out: What is the data transfer rate? What rise and fall times are required? And do you need one-directional or bi-directional translation?

Comment: Then please, both of you, by all means, skip this question.
If you are so full of yourself that you feel the need to tell a newbie  how wrong is he is that he omitted some specs, or how writing "3V3" instead of "3.3 V" deserves a downvote, you are clearly incapable of helping anyone, not to mention you don't understand the purpose of the voting system.
Thanks again for everyone who took the time to answer my question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I did it

Comment: For info: Arduino works at 3.3V as well, and you can run it at 16 MHz at 3.3V without issues (usually) if it's ok for you to run it out of specs.

Comment: @Olaf: Actually you didn't.  "3V3" is still there.  In any case, even if you were to fix it for the OP, it wouldn't mean anything.  It only teaches the OP that other people will fix messes for him.  He won't learn to do it right next time by being made to fix it this time.  In this case, the OP spent more time reacting childishly instead of fixing the problem, so he clearly has no interest in better communication.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I had forgotten the title, the rest is done and awaiting peer review :) I agree on the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any N-Channel MOSFET, not just BSS138.
It is pretty simple. This is bidirectional level converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH1RJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**UPDATE:**
By "any" I meant any jellybean small signal mosfet. Simply with low Vgs voltage threshold.

Comment: You cannot just use *any* MOSFET; most have a too-high gate threshold.

Comment: You are right. I meant any jellybean small signal mosfet. I will update it.

Comment: Will [IRF510PBF](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf510pbf.pdf) / [IRL540NPBF](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565fc2a62567) be a suitable replacement?

Comment: No, IRF510PBF / IRL540NPBF are not suitable. Those are power mosfets. They are beefy and costly to do just level conversions. IRL540NPBF will work, it has Vgs less than 2V. But it is better to use smaller mosfets for this task.

Comment: I found one more that i think will work [IRLU120NPBF](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr120npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566965182665) and is 30% cheaper than IRL540NPBF.

Comment: private, you are looking for bad types. This is again a power mosfet. You do not need such chunky TO-220 mosfet just for signal level converting. Yes, it will work, but it is really heavyweight for the task. If you want through-hole one, you can use TO-92 package, like 2N7000, BS170, etc.. If you want SMD one, you can use something like 2N7002, BSS138, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately my local retailers have horrible websites and i have to manually search every product datasheet, without any filtering whatsoever. Luckily i found BS170 in stock. Thanks a lot you for your help.

Comment: Yes, BS170 is pretty much a jellybean part ;) If you have problems with local suppliers, you could try ebay or aliexpress to get such basic parts. You can get 10 pieces of BS170 or 2N7000 under 1 USD. But you would have to wait for it a month.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your inputs are 5V tolerant.
If not, check if the ESP8266's inputs are diode protected first.

If not, I'd recommend connecting a diode between your 3.3V input and 3.3V supply (A on the input, K on the 3.3V supply).

You should also add a resistor in series with your 5V output to reduce the current when the 5V outputs a logic high.

You need to check however that you input accepts the resulting voltages etc

PS: This does not take many other aspects that you should take into account, like the signal frequencies for example.